# new line in HTML

Tags: html, newline, inline

I'm starting in html and I got some problems in it, my teacher is like "you got internet go search for it" but I couldn't find anything to get it to work, so sorry if it's a basic question...
So, my question is, in the follow image, I have a text under an image that I want to put under the text in the side of image and I also wanted to be able to add some text under that date "24 de Abril de 2014"...
There is an image to explain my problem:

[image]

And here is what I have, my Div:

```
<div class="inline" id="noticiaDiv">
    <tr
        <a href="noticia1.html" title="Deco defende venda de gás de botija de marca branca" aling="left">
            <img src="documentos_apoio/gas.jpg" width="170px" height="170px" style="vertical-align: top"></img>
        <a class="titulo" href="noticia1.html" target="_top">
            Deco defende venda de gás de botija de marca branca
            <br>
        </a>
        <font class="data" target="_top">24 de Abril de 2014</font>
    </tr>
</div>
```

and my css of the classes:

```css
div.inline {
    width: 1350px;
    float:left;
}
.data {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.titulo {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#noticaDiv {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="documentos_apoio/gas.jpg" alt="" width="170px" height="170px" style="vertical-align: top" /></td>
                <td><a class="titulo" href="noticia1.html">Deco defende venda de gás de botija de marca branca</a>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    24 de Abril de 2014
                    <br />
                    Some Text Here
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

or see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/872e3/)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<img align="left" ... >
```

Note that in HTML5 align is deprecated and css should be used instead

Comment: Didn't work... if I use the <br> for the new line the next go to the place that I posted in the image... if I remove the <br> it will merge with the text next to the image

Answer (score 0):

a lot of errors in your tags close your anchor tags and cross check for spelling errors like align. update what you have

Comment: I know that I may have lots of errors in here... but im completly lost in html... I'm doing it was a school project, my area is programming... and anything about websites... I'm just a noob...